# Windows device file does not return valid handle with python win32API

Tags: python, windows, driver

I am trying to open a device file in windows using python. I heard I needed to use win32 API. So I am using that, to open my file I need to perform the following this stackoverflow question : [Opening a handle to a device in Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212715/opening-a-handle-to-a-device-in-python-on-windows)

```py
import win32file as w32
self.receiver_handle = w32.CreateFile("\\\\.\\xillybus_read_32",  # file to open

w32.GENERIC_READ,  # desired access
w32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,  # shared mode
None,  # security attribute
w32.OPEN_EXISTING,  # creation distribution
w32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,  #flags and attributes
None)  # no template file
```

This results in the handle always returning 0.
Here is the API reference: http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32CreateFile.htm

The driver came with a barebones C program to test it and it works flawlessly, so it can't be the driver itself that is not properly working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, can you be sure you are running your Python program as Administrator?

Comment: I have tried and it does not seem to be the problem. I did have an error with missing number of argument, which I have fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API should not return zero.  It should return a `PyHANDLE` object.  I don't have your device, but opening an existing file works.  The 3rd parameter should be `w32.FILE_SHARE_READ` (or similar share mode value), however:

```
>>> import win32file as w32
>>> w32.CreateFile('blah.txt',w32.GENERIC_READ,w32.FILE_SHARE_READ,None,w32.OPEN_EXISTING,w32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,None)
<PyHANDLE:280>
```

If the file does not exist (or any other error), Python should raise an exception based on the `GetLastError()` code returned by the Win32 API called:

```
>>> w32.CreateFile('blah.txt',w32.GENERIC_READ,w32.FILE_SHARE_READ,None,w32.OPEN_EXISTING,w32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

If this doesn't help, edit your question to show the *exact* code you are running and the *exact* results of running the code.